# Sum consecutive pairs of elements in a list

Tags: python, list

I want to find sums of elements of the list by index0,index1 and index1,index2 and index2,index3, and so on.

Like:

```
my_list = [7, 5, 9, 4, 7, 11]  
sums = [12, 14, 13, 11, 18]  # 7+5, 5+9, 9+4, 4+7, 7+11
```

Comment: Related: [Sum of consecutive pairs in a list including a sum of the last element with the first](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63212888/7851470)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine :)

```
list=[7,5,9,4,7,11]
aspSum = []
i = 0
while i<len(list)-1:
   aspSum.append(list[i]+list[i+1])
   i+=1
```

Answer (score 5):

You just have to iterate through the indices:

```
l = [7, 5, 9, 4, 7, 11]  

res = [l[i] + l[i+1] for i in range(len(l)-1)]

print(res)
```

Output:

```
[12, 14, 13, 11, 18]
```

Comment: Pardon me, I'm still learning which method is the proffered method if the two are available, zip/map combination or list comprehension?

Comment: No asking because some higher up gave me a earful for answering a problem with a for loop instead of a zip map, not because I didn't know but he said that we should always use best practices and I just seen yours and you seem pretty deep in the game, I'm searching opinions views

Answer (score 3):

You can use `zip` and `sum` for a functional solution:

```
# don't shadow the built-in `list`
l = [7,5,9,4,7,11]
# generate all neighboring pairs
pairs = zip(l, l[1:])
# generate all sums of pairs
sums = list(map(sum, pairs))

print(sums)  # [12, 14, 13, 11, 18]
```

Comment: Thank you. this my solution. But can you explain slicing part i.e l[1: ],             I know list [start: end, step]

Comment: I used it to create the neighbors. Just do it in the REPL. Its basic slicing.