# Sum of consecutive pairs in a list including a sum of the last element with the first

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a list of elements like `[1,3,5,6,8,7]`.
I want a list of sums of two consecutive elements of the list in a way that the last element is also added with the first element of the list.
I mean in the above case, I want this list:
`[4,8,11,14,15,8]`

But when it comes to the addition of the last and the first element during for loop, index out of range occurs.
Consider the following code:

```
List1 = [1,3,5,6,8,7]
List2 = [List1[i] + List1[i+1] for i in range (len(List1))]

print(List2)
```

Comment: Is the last `8` in the list you want supposed to be an expected result?

Comment: Shouldn’t len -1 or % len do the trick?

Comment: @Ederic Oytas, yes it is the sum of last and the first element or vice versa.

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski yes, i have figured it out. But is there any way to get the sum of last and first element when index reaches 5 (i.e the index of last element)?

Comment: @Aivar Paalberg, in that case i will not get last value which is the sum of 1st and the Last element.

Comment: Change `i+1` to `(i+1) % len(List1)`

Comment: @AdnanAkram - you are right regarding len - 1, but modulo should deliver expected result (look at Steven Rumbalski comment above)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List2 = [List1[i] + List1[(i+1)%len(List1)] for i in range (len(List1))]
```

Comment: I like it, although it is somewhat inefficient since the modulus operator is really only useful for the last element.

Answer (score 4):

```
[List1[i] + List1[(i+1) % len(List1)] for i in range(len(List1))]
```

or

```
[sum(tup) for tup in zip(List1, List1[1:] + [List1[0]])]
```

or

```
[x + y for x, y in zip(List1, List1[1:] + [List1[0]])]
```

Answer (score 2):

Because of the `i+1`, the index goes out of range

```
List1 = [1,3,5,6,8,7]
List2 = [List1[i-1] + List1[i] for i in range (len(List1))]

print (List2)
```

This way kinda works
Result:

```
[8, 4, 8, 11, 14, 15]
```

Comment: It misses the last integer (8)

Comment: No, the first element is the last integer.

Answer (score 2):

This rotates the list

```
In [9]: List1[1:] + List1[:1]                                                                 
Out[9]: [3, 5, 6, 8, 7, 1]
```

So following works perfectly

```
In [8]: [x + y for x, y in zip(List1, List1[1:] + List1[:1])]                                 
Out[8]: [4, 8, 11, 14, 15, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're actually doing is adding consecutive items in the list, but when you reach the last index, your code still adds one to the last index, which results in an index out of range error. You should consider using:

```
List1 = [1,3,5,6,8,7]
List2 = [List1[i] + List1[i+1] for i in range (len(List1) - 1)]
List2.append(List1[0] + List1[-1])

print (List2)
```

Comment: Don't know why you are down other, your answer is one of two that produces the requested result

Answer (score 1):

As you are running it to the len(List1) - 1
So when, i value will be len(List1) - 1, then i + 1 will be out of range (i.e. len(List1)),
So you can try this solution:

```
List2 = [List1[i-1] + List1[i] for i in range (len(List1))]
```

Or you can do:

```
List2 = [List1[i] + List1[i+1] for i in range (len(List1)-1)]
```

Or you can use any other logic also.
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

When `i == 5`, then it will enter the "if" statement and `i` is set to `-1`.
Note that `List[-1]` is the same as `List[len(List) - 1]`, which means that `List[i+1]` will become `List[0]`, the first element of the list.

```
for i in range(len(List1)):
    if i == len(List1) - 1:
        i = -1
    List2.append(List1[i] + List1[i+1])
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain how this code answers the question, so that it is useful not just for the OP but also other users with the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another ugly solution:

```
List1 = [1,3,5,6,8,7] 
List2 = [List1[i] + (List1+[List1[0]])[i+1] for i in range (len(List1))]

print (List2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Some more pythonic answers that weren't answered yet:

Using `map` can be more readable:

```py
List2 = list(map(sum, zip(List1, List1[1:] + List1[:1])))
```

You can also use `itertools` to offset the list:

```py
import itertools
List2 = list(map(sum, zip(List1, itertools.islice(itertools.cycle(List1), 1, None))))
```